# Printing only significant digits in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

Given this simple python script:

```
import sys, math

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    num = float(sys.argv[i])
    print('sin(%f) = %f' % (num, math.sin(num)))
```

Run with these arguments:

> python hw2a.py 1.4 -0.1 4 99

I want this output:

```
sin(1.4)=0.98545
sin(-0.1)=-0.0998334
sin(4)=-0.756802
sin(99)=-0.999207
```

However when I run it, I get a lot of insignificant digits (well, zeroes) behind the decimal point and the significant digits. I know I can specify a fixed number of decimals using for instance %.3f, but how can I make it print all digits behind the decimal point, until there are no significant digits left?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's hard to define 'significance'. 0 does not mean non-sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format with `%g`:

```
In [16]: a = [1.4, -0.1, 4, 99]

In [18]: for num in a:
    ...:     print('sin(%g) = %g' % (num, math.sin(num)))
    ...:     
sin(-0.1) = -0.0998334
sin(4) = -0.756802
sin(99) = -0.999207
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys.argv[i]`, no need to convert i to a float and back to a string and `g` to format:

```
import sys, math

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    num = float(sys.argv[i])
    print "sin({}) = {:g}".format(sys.argv[i],math.sin(num))

python foo.py 1.4 -0.1 4 99
sin(1.4) = 0.98545
sin(-0.1) = -0.0998334
sin(4) = -0.756802
sin(99) = -0.999207
```

If the data is not manually entered as @mhawke suggests, you can use:

`print "sin({:g}) = {:g}".format(num, math.sin(num))`

Comment: This is OK, but what if `sys.argv[i] = '1.4000'` for example.

Comment: @mhawke, if you did not want them why would you enter them? It was the `float(sys.argv[i])` that was adding the zeros.

Comment: Just pointing that out, pedantic I know, and it might be fine for the OP. What if the input is not hand entered, perhaps from another script. I think that `print "sin({:g}) = {:g}".format(num, math.sin(num))` seems the best solution.

Comment: @mhawke, True, I just presumed it was more a case of overlooking the fact the sys.argv[i] could be used instead of using num, I will add your suggestion to my answer to cover both cases